# Common email pitfalls for social login integrations

Tags: login, authentication, social

We are planning to implement social logins on our site. (Potentially via a service like [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) or [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).) For us the user's email is key, so we will implement only services that expose the user's email.

What are the common pitfalls when integrating social logins for a site? And what are the best practices to handle them?

Examples would be:

- User changes email with his social identity provider, how would we
  know?
- User deletes his social account? How to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some services like facebook provide means of notification when a user deauthorizes your application, this might also indicate deletion (Via a Web callback).

You could load the E-Mail adress using the token you aquired from the user every time you want to send an email to him/her. You may also reload the E-Mail Address every time the user accesses your application to keep away the load from mass e-mailing times.

The best way to solve this UX-Wise will be to add an additional prompt after login for the user to provide his/her E-Mail, prefilled with the social network provided E-Mail Address. The user will notice the fact that you are storing an E-Mail address for notification purposes and he or she might have to manually change it. Inside this step, you could also require a checkbox for explicit user consent regarding the E-Mail notifications.

PS: Provide a link to unsubscription and E-Mail settings in every E-Mail you send! This will remove the hassle of navigating through your application if your users are annoyed.